# JSON trouble; deserialising to a datatable

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am trying to load JSON into a SQL database using JSON.net.

I've had no issues with other JSON responses however the following format doesn't seem to deserialise correctly.

```
    {"Report":["2012m01d01","2012m01d02","2012w01","2012m01","2012m01d03","2012m01d04","2012m01d05","2012m01d06","2012m01d07","2012m01d08"],
"Realtime":null}
```

Could anybody provide some insight into why this would be? I'm using the following code to deserialise with.

```
public void Deserialize(String jsonText, ref DataTable dt)
        {
            JsonSerializer json = new JsonSerializer();
            json.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            json.ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace;
            json.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;
            json.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(jsonText);
            JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr);
            dt = (DataTable)json.Deserialize(reader, typeof(DataTable));

            reader.Close();
        }
```

Any ideas on what the best approach to solving this would be? This works fine with other JSON responses!

Thanks in advance

Comment: "the following format doesn't seem to deserialise correctly" do you receive any error or results are not expected? What error and what result? Can you give some example where it works fine?

Comment: Are you using .NET 4.0 if so here is a link that will help you out as well.. http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2010/08/22/using-c-4.0-and-dynamic-to-parse-json.aspx

Comment: It doesn't generate any error unfortuantely. It just doesn't seem to deserialise. The following deserialises fine though.       [{"accountID":1,"profileID":null,"name":"Pages","ID":"18d039ae0360","language":null,"type":null,"Category":null,"IsHierarchy":false,"IntervalsEnabled":true,"IsRealtimeCompatible":true,"properties":null}, (and so on)

Answer (score 0):

JSON is able to hold hirarchial information, that does not translate into a single datatable, but rather into several using a dataset and table relationships.

I put your json in http://jsonlint.com validator and formatter

you say this deserializes with no problems

```
{
    "accountID": 1,
    "profileID": null,
    "name": "Pages",
    "ID": "18d039ae0360",
    "language": n‌​ull,
    "type": null,
    "Category": null,
    "IsHierarchy": false,
    "IntervalsEnabled": true,
    "IsRe‌​altimeCompatible": true,
    "properties": null
}
```

this is a single object

but this doesn't deserialize properly.

```
{
    "Report": [
        "2012m01d01",
        "2012m01d02",
        "2012w01",
        "2012m01",
        "2012m01d03",
        "2012m01d04",
        "2012m01d05",
        "2012m01d06",
        "2012m01d07",
        "2012m01d08"
    ],
    "Realtime": null
}
```

Actually your problem is data handling not serializion

the first is a single object and can be deserialized into a DataTable
and the other is an object that holds a reference to a list of report objects.

therefore you need to manually write a converter from your object to two dataTables

this code works, and i'm sure you can create a conversion function for your two tables

```
           var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {

            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include

        };
        JsonSerializer json = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);

        json.Error += (x, y) =>
        {
            var s = y.ErrorContext;
            var t = y.CurrentObject;

        };

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(jsonString);
        JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr);


        var o = json.Deserialize<ClsReport>(reader);

        string sf = o.ReportItems[2];
```

Hope this helps